# scan-array CUDA

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to scan a simple array using CUDA but it seems there is something wrong with the code below..I am trying to find what i am doing wrong but i can't.Can anyone please help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


__global__ void prescan(int *g_odata, int *g_idata, int n){

    extern __shared__ int temp[];// allocated on invocation
    int thid = threadIdx.x;
    int offset = 1;
    temp[2*thid] = g_idata[2*thid]; // load input into shared memory
    temp[2*thid+1] = g_idata[2*thid+1];


    for (int d = n>>1; d > 0; d >>= 1){ // build sum in place up the tree
        __syncthreads();
        if (thid < d){

            int ai = offset*(2*thid+1)-1;
            int bi = offset*(2*thid+2)-1;
            temp[bi] += temp[ai];
        }
        offset *= 2;
    }

    if (thid == 0) { temp[n - 1] = 0; } // clear the last element

    for (int d = 1; d < n; d *= 2){ // traverse down tree & build scan
        offset >>= 1;
        __syncthreads();
        if (thid < d){

            int ai = offset*(2*thid+1)-1;
            int bi = offset*(2*thid+2)-1;
            int t = temp[ai];
            temp[ai] = temp[bi];
            temp[bi] += t;
        }
    }

    __syncthreads();

    g_odata[2*thid] = temp[2*thid]; // write results to device memory
    g_odata[2*thid+1] = temp[2*thid+1];
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int i;
    int *input = 0;
    int *output = 0;
    int *g_idata = 0;
    int *g_odata = 0;

    int numblocks = 1;
    int radix = 16;

    input = (int*)malloc(numblocks*radix*sizeof(int));
    output = (int*)malloc(numblocks*radix*sizeof(int));

    cudaMalloc((void**)&g_idata, numblocks*radix*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&g_odata, numblocks*radix*sizeof(int));

    for(i=0; i<numblocks*radix; i++){
            input[i] = 1 + 2*i;
    }

    for(i=0; i<numblocks*radix; i++){
        printf("%d   ", input[i]);
    }

    cudaMemcpy(g_idata, input, numblocks*radix*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    prescan<<<1,8>>>(g_odata, g_idata, numblocks*radix);

    cudaThreadSynchronize();

    cudaMemcpy(output, g_odata, numblocks*radix*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for(i=0; i<numblocks*radix; i++){
        printf("%d   ", output[i]);
    }

    free(input);
    free(output);
    cudaFree(g_idata);
    cudaFree(g_odata);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is this: 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0.I want to have this output: 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 0 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100 121 144 169 196 225

Comment: You are launching the kernel without specifying a shared memory size. It probably isn't launching or running to completion and returning an error, but you have no error checking, so you don't see the error. I couldn't be bothered trying to understand the kernel, it might still be broken, but with more fundamental problems it would be a waste of everyone's time to try.

Comment: `prescan<<<1,8, numblocks * radix * sizeof(int) >>>(g_odata, g_idata, numblocks*radix);`

Comment: These comments should be answers. :)

Comment: the code of the kernel is right.I took it from NVIDIA samples http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch39.html.there is no problem with the compilation.But instead of taking this output 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 0 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100 121 144 169 196 225, i'm taking the last 16 elements all zeros..

Comment: @user1420142: Are you even reading the comments? The problem seems to be in how you're calling the kernel, not the kernel itself.

Comment: OK thank you! It works now. The problem was in the kernel call as you said..

Answer (score 1):

Just go through this code to implement scan in parallel environment.
The algorithm which I implemented here is Hillis Steele exclusive scan.I implemented algorithm through shared memory, it will definitely improve the execution time for the large data set.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
__global__ void scan(int *d_in,int *d_out,int n)
{
    extern __shared__ int sdata[];
    int i;
    int tid = threadIdx.x;
    sdata[tid] = d_in[tid];
    for (i = 1; i <n; i <<= 1)
     {

        if (tid>=i)
         {
            sdata[tid] +=sdata[tid-i];
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }
    d_out[tid] = sdata[tid];
     __syncthreads();
 }

int main()
 {

    int h_in[16],h_out[16];
     int i,j;
     for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        h_in[i] = 2*i+1;
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        printf("%d ", h_in[i]);
   int *d_in;
   int *d_out;
   cudaMalloc((void**)&d_in, sizeof(int)* 16);
   cudaMalloc((void**)&d_out, sizeof(int)* 16);
   cudaMemcpy(d_in, h_in, sizeof(int) * 16, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

   scan <<<1, 16, sizeof(int)*16 >>>(d_in,d_out, 16);

   cudaMemcpy(h_out, d_out, sizeof(int) * 16, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
   for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
      printf("%d ", h_out[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: this code can work (with the right __syncthreads(); at the right place) only if there is ONLY one block of thread. This mean that you can use this only with array with small size because you will be limitated from the maximum number of threads per block